# Python Tkinter multiprocessing progress

Tags: python, tkinter, multiprocessing

For my work, I frequently have to collect reasonably large datasets from a MySQL database, e.g. several parameters for several locations, and store that data in a CSV file per location. For this, I've written a small GUI. Since, the data has to be stored per location, I thought I'd take advantages of my 8-thread CPU and use the multiprocessing package to query the database per location. This works just fine, but I also want to keep track of how far the data retrieval and file writing is.

The trick with using multiprocessing together with Tkinter was to put the function that is called in the multiprocessing outside of the GUI class, but how do I get information from that function back into the class?

My code so far:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
from tkinter import *
import os
import pandas
import pymysql


class App:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.stations = None
        self.variables = None
        self.startdtg = None
        self.enddtg = None
        self.outputlocation = "C:/Users/test"
        self.processes = []

        Label(master, text="Locations:").grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W, columnspan=3)
        self.locationEntry = Entry(master)
        self.locationEntry.grid(row=0, column=1, sticky=EW, columnspan=3)

        Label(master, text="Enter variables:").grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.varEntry = Entry(master)
        self.varEntry.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=EW, columnspan=3)

        Label(master, text="Start DTG:").grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.startEntry = Entry(master)
        self.startEntry.grid(row=2, column=1, sticky=EW)

        Label(master, text="End DTG:").grid(row=2, column=2, sticky=W)
        self.endEntry = Entry(master)
        self.endEntry.grid(row=2, column=3, sticky=EW)

        Label(master, text="Output location:").grid(row=3, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.outputEntry = Entry(master)
        self.outputEntry.grid(row=3, column=1, columnspan=2, sticky=EW)

        self.startButton = Button(master, text="Start", command=self.get_data)
        self.startButton.grid(row=5, column=1, sticky=EW)

    def get_data(self):
        self.update_variables()
        self.collect_data()

    def update_variables(self):
        self.stations = [station.strip() for station in self.locationEntry.get().split(",")]
        self.variables = [variable.strip() for variable in self.varEntry.get().split(",")]
        self.startdtg = self.startEntry.get()
        self.enddtg = self.endEntry.get()
        self.outputlocation = os.path.join(self.outputlocation, self.outputEntry.get())

    def collect_data(self):
        for station in self.stations:
            p = Process(target=query_database, args=(station, self.variables, self.startdtg, self.enddtg, self.outputlocation))
            self.processes.append(p)
            p.start()


def query_database(station, variables, startdtg, enddtg, outputlocation):
    """"Function that collects and writes data to local drive"""


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

To be clear: this code works fine. It produces this GUI:
[image: GUI v1]

What I want, is a GUI like this:

[image: GUI v2]

With the  part showing the progress of the query_database function, meaning it has to update when a step in that function has been completed.

How would I approach this? Also, feel free to give any comments about my coding, I'm still learning the basics of GUIs and setting up classes.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7310511/how-to-create-downloading-progress-bar-in-ttk) may help.

Comment: @Nae Looks promising, but I was thinking more in the line of text, with options like "In queue", "Collecting data", "Writing output".

Comment: Well, can't you manually change the label's text while inside `query_database` method? As in after each line put `some_label['text'] = "now this is happening"`?

Comment: Or in other words can you update `query_database` method to its complete working form?

Comment: @Nae, he can't because it's not thread safe practice, since `query_database` executed in an another thread, while all tcl-related stuff needs to be originated from the same thread. The common tactic - populating a queue from a thread while asynchronously checking it via `after` from a main one (something like [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42786334/6634373)).

Comment: @CommonSense It isn't threading though, it's multiprocessing. Doesn't that account for some difference in the matter?

Comment: @Nae, In this *context* there's [no much difference between a thread and a process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3044580/multiprocessing-vs-threading-python). Sure, `multiprocessing` and `threading` aren't a same thing, but it still a must to plan communication with `tkinter` somehow. As far as I know, of course!

Comment: And a main question is a clear `how do I get information from that function back into the class`. [So, a `Queue` or a `Pipe` is definitely an answer!](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's sum what was said in comments:

1. To get information from function, which executed in another process,
   you should [communicate](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#exchanging-objects-between-processes) with function's process with either a [`Queue`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Queue) or a [`Pipe`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Pipe).
2. While you have a channel to communicate with - keep checking
   continiously for messages via self-scheduling
   [`after`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/widget.htm#Tkinter.Widget.after-method).
3. Keep in mind that idea to pass a `Label` or anything `tk`-related to
   that process isn't an option, since it isn't a thread/process-safe
   practice.

After all of this you should come with something similar to this approach:

```
try:
    import Tkinter as tk              # Python 2
    import ttk
    import Queue as queue
except ImportError:
    import tkinter as tk              # Python 3
    import tkinter.ttk as ttk
    import queue

import multiprocessing as mp
import time


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.minsize(width=400, height=25)

        self.label = tk.Label(self, text='Waiting for "work"')
        self.label.pack(expand=True, fill='both')

        self.progressbar = ttk.Progressbar(self, orient='horizontal', value=0, maximum=3, mode='determinate')
        self.progressbar.pack(fill='x')

        self.button = tk.Button(self, text='Start', command=self.start_work)
        self.button.pack(fill='x')

        self.queue = mp.Queue()
        self.process = None

    def start_work(self):
        self.process = mp.Process(target=work, args=(self.queue,))
        self.button.configure(state='disabled')
        self.process.start()
        self.periodic_call()

    def periodic_call(self):
        #   check a queue once
        self.check_queue()

        #   if exit code is None - process is on the run and we should re-schedule check
        if self.process.exitcode is None:
            self.after(100, self.periodic_call)
        #   things are executed
        else:
            self.process.join()
            self.button.configure(state='normal')
            self.label.configure(text='Waiting for "work"')
            self.progressbar.configure(value=0)

    def check_queue(self):
        #   common check of the queue
        while self.queue.qsize():
            try:
                self.label.configure(text=self.queue.get(0))
                self.progressbar.configure(value=self.progressbar['value'] + 1)
            except queue.Empty:
                pass


def work(working_queue):
    for type_of_work in ['Combobulationg Discombobulator', 'Pointing towards space',
                         'Calculating Ultimate Answer']:
        working_queue.put(type_of_work)
        time.sleep(1.5)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = App()
    app.mainloop()
```